# Python: Start each newline with a specific character

Tags: python

I have the following string, and would like to begin each new line with "1, 2, 3," respectively.

```
mystring = "27 C
27 C
32 C
27 C
25 C"
```

(There may be more or less numbers in reality, but they will always be that length and format). I would then like this string to look like this;

```
mystring = "1, 27
2, 27
3, 32
4, 27
5, 25"
```

I've tried various things, but I've only ever managed to get the "1, " AFTER the value (using replace on the 'C' or the newline character)

I'm not sure what else to try. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: What happened to `C`?

Comment: It's not needed so I did replace('C','')

Comment: this isn't a valid string variable, did you mean to use `"""` instead of `"`?

Comment: The string comes from a command which is ran on my laptop (to print the internal temperatures). I simply put the `mystring = "...` to make my question easier to understand. So, yeah, I guess it would be `"""` but that isn't actually in the 'real' code. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
x = '\n'.join([str(i + 1) + ', ' + n for i,n in enumerate(mystring.split()[::2])])

print x

1, 27
2, 27
3, 32
4, 27
5, 25
```

Between the parens of the join method, there is a list comprehension. `mystring.split()` produces:
 `['27', 'C', '27', 'C', '32', 'C', '27', 'C', '25', 'C']`

Then the slicing `[::2]` takes every second element of that list*(starting with the 0th)* with the result:

```
['27', '27', '32', '27', '25']
```

This list is enumerated, for example:

```
for i in enumerate(mystring.split()[::2]):
    print i

(0, '27')
(1, '27')
(2, '32')
(3, '27')
(4, '25')
```

the first elements of each tuple is an int.. so:

`str(i + 1) + ', ' + n for i, n` **in the above enumerated tuples** , joined by `'\n'` via the `join` method of strings...gives the final result:

```
    1, 27
    2, 27
    3, 32
    4, 27
    5, 25
```

Comment: This works, however I needed to remove `[::2]` to get it to work correctly. When `[::2]` was there, every second line was missing from the output. Thanks for the good explanation :)

Comment: Strange, it works perfectly for me with the [::2]. It should be cutting out the C's from mystring.split(). Glad I could help

Comment: he said he removed the Cs from the input in a comment, but it's a deceiving description.  `str.splitlines()` will give you the list that you want.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Try the `enumerate` method:

```
for i, s in enumerate(mystring.split('\n'), 1):
    print(i, s)
```

You could easily adapt this for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```
>> z = '\n'.join('{}, {}'.format(c+1, s) for c,s in enumerate(mystring.split('\n')))
>>> print(z)
1, 27 C
2, 27 C
3, 32 C
4, 27 C
5, 25 C
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost works however, every second line is missing. Do you have any ideas to why that might happen? Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for your help and contribution.